# Where is the data directory in Redis?

Tags: redis, directory, server

After writing some data to a redis server, I could read the data from a client.
However, how can I find the data directory on the file system?

Comment: `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 150):

Quickest method: use redis-cli.

```
redis-cli config get dir
```

If you have authentication configured, you will need to pass that in using `-a password` Replacing "password" with your password.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it returned a completely wrong directory. I found my config at `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf`.

Comment: It gave you the config for the instance you connected to. If not, file a bug.

Comment: this command will return the application directory location based on the redis.conf file or default config (if you don't have one) not the config file location

Comment: This outputs two directories; which is correct?

Comment: Is there a response that could be consistent when running Docker? For instance when running Mongo I map volumes like so: "'./.mongo:/data/db'", pretty useful to control the location of data during local dev. I am trying to find an equivalent for Redis.

Answer (score 41):

Find your Redis configuration directory, probably `/etc/redis`. Then look in the config file called `redis.conf` and find the line that starts `dir`.

It will look similar to this:

```
dir /etc/redis/database
```

This will do the job slowly but surely if you can't be bothered to look :-)

```
sudo find / -name "redis.conf" -exec grep "^dir" {} \; 2> /dev/null
dir /etc/redis
```

or if you want the config filename as well:

```
sudo find / -name "redis.conf" -exec grep -H "^dir" {} \; 2> /dev/null
/private/etc/redis/redis.conf:dir /etc/redis
```

Other possibilities you can check are whether Redis was started with a custom config file as its first parameter like this:

```
redis-server /path/to.custom/config-file
```

or with the `dir` option set on the commandline like this:

```
redis-server dir /path/to/data
```

Use

```
ps -aef | grep redis
```

to look for these options.

Answer (score 4):

Because Redis config file can be located in several possible places (depending on the system or container, such as `/opt/redis/` in my case), a general solution to find the currently configured location of the RDB file (as set using `dir` in `redis.conf` - if config file is used at all*) is:

```
$ cat $(cd / && find | grep redis.conf) | grep dir
```

*Note that true to its simplicity Redis by default ships without any config files (using built-in configuration which depends on the version, see [docs](https://redis.io/topics/config)), and this is indeed the case for the official `redis:latest` container.